# MouseMove Event Registers False Inputs

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, desktop-application

I have an ellipse in the code below which has a mouse move event. Now everything is good unless I use mouse.capture on the element.
The mouse move event gets fired immediately I apply mouse.capture on the element even if I don't move my mouse, and also moving the position of the element by using setleft property also fires the mouse move event even if I don't move my mouse at all! Is this supposed to happen? And if there's a solution I badly need it..
The code below will generate the exact problem...

```
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace Test
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public Ellipse elp;
        public Point clickPoint;
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            testcanv.Background = Brushes.Transparent;
        }

        private void down(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            clickPoint = e.GetPosition(testcanv);
            if (e.ChangedButton == MouseButton.Left)
            {
                elp = new Ellipse
                {
                    Stroke = Brushes.Blue,
                    StrokeThickness = 2,
                    Width = 200,
                    Height = 200,
                    Margin = new Thickness(-250)
                };
                Canvas.SetLeft(elp, clickPoint.X);
                Canvas.SetTop(elp, clickPoint.Y);
                elp.MouseMove += circle_move;
                testcanv.Children.Add(elp);
            }
        }

        private void circle_move(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            text.Text += "Moved,";
        }

        private async void click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Mouse.Capture(elp, CaptureMode.Element);
            await Task.Delay(1000);
            Canvas.SetLeft(elp, 100);
            Canvas.SetTop(elp, 100);
            await Task.Delay(500);
            Mouse.Capture(null);
        }
    }
}
```

And here is my XAML

```
<Window x:Class="Test.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:balchal"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="50"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition Height="50"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Canvas x:Name="testcanv" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" MouseDown="down"/>
        <Button Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Content="Button" Click="click"/>
        <TextBox x:Name="text" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Width="300" Margin="10"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Thanks in advance... I really appreciate any kind of help...

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I am trying to move the ellipse by dragging it.

Comment: If you want to move the `Ellipse` around, then why are you adding a new one every time the mouse moves? Shouldn't you just change the position of the one that's already there?

Comment: Yes that's what I am doing on my actual code.. I just created this simple code to reproduce the problem.. the position changing process becomes disrupted because of this behaviour stated above

Answer (score 0):

I may be wrong, but I believe that the MouseMove event always fires when capturing

The simplest solution, if it's happening consistently, is probably just to store the state in the `click` event and check for it at the start of the `move` event: returning immediately and resetting the var.

```
bool CapturedFlag = false;

private void MoveEvent(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    if(CapturedFlag = true)
    {
        CapturedFlag = false;
        return;
    }

    // other code
}

private async void CaptureEvent(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    CapturedFlag = true;

    // other code
}
```

Comment: if I release mouse capture on mousemove then I don't find any point on capturing the mouse at all.. Also it didn't solve the problem.